# Iterating over Keys of a dictionary in For and If loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, break

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```py
websites = {
    "instagram": f'https://www.instagram.com/{username}',
    "facebook": f'https://www.facebook.com/{username}'
    }
```

And a For loop for iterating over keys of the dictionary

```py
for key in websites.keys():
    keys = str(key)
    # print(keys)
    if keys == target:
        # print(target)
        # print(keys)
        search_web(username, websites[key])
        break
```

My `search_web` function:

```py
def search_web(username, tgt):
    print("search_web is running")
    r = requests.get(tgt)
    print(tgt)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Got it ' + username + ' in ' + tgt)
    elif r.status_code == 400:
        print('Not Found in ' + username + ' at ' + tgt)
```

This is what the Output looks like:

```
python search_user.py -u vybhav_72954 -t instagram github


Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
```

Now I understand what's going on, The Instagram loop is running 9 times, because of 9 literal characters and similarly, Github is running because of 6 literal characters.

I understand that the `break` statement is used to break out of `If` loop, once the condition is met, but in this case, rather than breaking the condition we are looping again. I tried changing the position of break and my function call, but still the problem persists, am sure this is a basic mistake, can someone guide me here.

Expected Output:

```
Got it vybhav_72954 in https://www.instagram.com/vybhav_72954
Not Found vybhav_72954 at https://www.github.com/vybhav_72954
```

Just in case if it's needed, the `argparse` function:

```py
def parser_input():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-u", "--usernames", help="Enter the username.", type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--targets", help="Enter the website(s).", type=str, required=True, nargs='+')

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()

    return parser.parse_args()
```

My `main` function also has a for loop, which triggers `inputs` function which contains the for loop, dictionary and the function call to `search_web` function.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg = parser_input()
    # listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in arg.targets])
    for i in range(len(arg.targets)):
        for l in arg.targets[i]:
            inputs(arg.usernames, arg.targets[i])
```

I have used the for loop to run the code separately on the strings contained in list generated by `arg.target` [as it has `nargs='+'`]

EDIT - Pastebin for Complete code [click here](https://pastebin.com/Mf4UKsp0)

Comment: From taking a quick look, I am unsure what's being recieved as the data that is showing is coming from     r = requests.get(tgt), which is where the issue might be at (Or very likely that I am missing something). This might not be a solution, but you could perhaps get rid of duplicate entries? In any case, if you can post what's being sent in that function exactly I think that could make it easier to help.

Comment: In the last code snippet, the inner for cycle is not required. If you look at your output, you will see that instagram gets searched 9 times, while github 6. If you look at the word "instagram" and "github" they respectively comprise 9 and 6 characters. This is no coincidence. In the inner loop, you are looping through each character in the words passed to the `targets` argument. Remove the for loop, unindent the block, and you should obtain the expected output, no `break required`.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle Hopefully this will [help](https://pastebin.com/Mf4UKsp0)

Comment: Let me take a look, meanwhile I think @gionni 's suggestion might fix it here. Will take a look regardless just in case.

Comment: @gionni Thank you for the suggestion. I can't even remember the Logic I used at this point when I made that `for` loop in `main`

@ZaidAlShattle As you said, his suggestion is correct, thank you for the response.